RabbitMQ and PHP cannot connect to channel
I'm very new to RabbitMQ and trying to add to the RabbitMQ Queue. This is my connection part of the class which connects to RabbitMQ. The error occurs on the line which gets the channel from the connection, because when I only connect it does not fail. What am I doing wrong?
function connect($host, $port, $user, $password, $vhost = '/') {
        return AMQPStreamConnection::create_connection([
            ['host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'vhost' => $vhost]
        ],
        [
            'insist' => false,
            'login_method' => 'AMQPLAIN',
            'login_response' => null,
            'locale' => 'en_US',
            'connection_timeout' => 3.0,
            'read_write_timeout' => 3.0,
            'context' => null,
            'keepalive' => true,
            'heartbeat' => 0
        ]);
    }


    public function __construct($host, $port, $user, $password, $queue, $vhost = '/')
    {
        try {
            $this->connection = $this->connect($host, $port, $user, $password, $vhost);
            $this->channel = $this->connection->channel();
            $this->queue = $queue;
            $this->channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
        } catch (AMQPConnectionClosedException $e) {
            log_message('error', 'RabbitMQ connection error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        } catch (AMQPIOException $e) {
            log_message('error', 'RabbitMQ IO error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            log_message('error', 'RabbitMQ general error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
    }

The RabbitMQ log shows that the user was authenticated
connection <0.1190.0> ([::1]:52990 -> [::1]:5672): user 'xxxx' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'my_vhost'

The moment I select the channel, there is a crash log entry (exception exit: {unexpected_message,{'EXIT',#Port<0.413>,einval}})
$this->channel = $this->connection->channel();

Centos 9, php 8.2, php-amqplib 3.6.0, erlang 26.

When checking isConnected, it shows true, just to add.

I found the issue (more or less).
I was using RabbitMQ version 3.9 which has some issue with the php library and ssl. I needed to remove and update the rabbitmq installation to 3.13.x
Which is compotible with the latest library.
